# Agility Training?

Tags: workout-routines, training

Everyone here is trying to max out their strength attribute and for some their charisma attribute with aesthetic muscles.

But what about agility?

I want to be able to dodge, fall from heights unharmed, jump on walls to climb them, butterfly swim, and dance like a god.

Are there any workout routines out there that focus on agility?

Comment: (Jumping) falling from heights or jump on walls to climb them sounds like parkour--which certainly incorporates a lot of agility.  If that is your goal, I'd check out https://americanparkour.com/category/workouts/
They've had many instruction videos/segments (also youtube is often a good source) as well as daily workouts (which I think have ended, but no reason you can't do the old daily workouts).

Comment: Olympic weightlifting may be an option. From what i understand it requires a lot of flexibility and makes you explosive which should enable you to jump high etc.

Comment: Are you just trying to get some possible activities that would in theory increase 'agility' for your main SO Worldbuilding, or are you actually trying to get real life things that you personally could do? In the real world you generally should do the activity that you want to improve in. You want to be able to dodge? Get someone to throw punches at you. You want to fall from heights? Start progressively jumping off higher things. Swim? Swim. Dance like a god? Take a dance class.